# URL Rewrite and redirect

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am having a small issue, I want to place rewrite url and redirect rule both. For example, I want to show content of abc.php when someone open abc.html and this can be done with url rewriting:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule    ^abc\.html$    abc.php [NC,L]
```

But what if some one opens abc.php directly in browser, I want to send them on abc.html and when I place 301 redirect it doesn't work as it generates loop.

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /abc\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /abc.html [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^abc\.html$ abc.php [NC,L]
```

Comment: Great anubhav, its working , can you pls explain working of:                                                                                               RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /abc\.php[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /abc.html [R=301,L]

Comment: FIrst redirect rule uses `THE_REQUEST ` variable that represents original request received by Apache from your browser and it doesn't get overwritten after execution of some rewrite rules.