# Redirecting WordPress page without changing the URL or doing a 301

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a URL like `https://mydomain/pages/123_share` 
but the corresponding WordPress page would be `https://mydomain/pages/123/`

How can I do this using `.htaccess`, WordPress wp-engine, etc.? Here, the problem is I cannot use 301 redirect. I need the content of that page served. That means whenever I type the first URL, I need to give the content of the second URL without passing additional HTTP headers or changing the URL.

How can I do that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [URL Rewrite and redirect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35794507/url-rewrite-and-redirect)

Answer (score 0):

If you have `mod_proxy` enabled you just use the same kind of rule as you would for an external redirect, but proxy it:

```
 RewriteRule ^pages/123_share$ https://mydomain/pages/123/ [NS,P]
```

The page should should have a `<link rel=canonical …` for SEO.